# how to install specific version of HHVM in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, hhvm

I have installed the **HHVM version 3.8.0 debug** version in Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

But this particular version has bug when **HHVM** crashes the stack-trace log file is empty ([HHVM github issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5631))

```
HipHop VM 3.8.0 (dbg)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.8.0-0-gbb32f8d645b28561d8491870c44730b9b3f08d35
Repo schema: 74bee5d310450724cfd49245fd6c2e1e4323b10a
```

So i would like to downgrade HHVM version to 3.7.3 debug. what are the steps to downgrade HHVM?

Answer (score 1):

> But this particular version has bug when HHVM crashes the stack-trace log file is empty

Can you attach GDB as I asked in the github issue so we can try to track down the actual problem for you?

> So i would like to downgrade HHVM version to 3.7.3 debug. what are the steps to downgrade HHVM?

The 3.7 series is unsupported as of the 3.8 release and won't be receiving security updates. You can technically pull the old deb off of dl.hhvm.com manually, but I would strongly caution against this.

If you want to downgrade, you're going to be much better off sticking with the [3.6 LTS series](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Long-term-support-%28LTS%29). That page has the full details of how to stick to an LTS release, but the gist is that you change

```
deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

in your apt configuration to

```
deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu trusty-lts-3.6 main
```

You will probably have to uninstall and then reinstall HHVM in order to get apt to actually downgrade the package after the config change.